# select case selection in geth 1.9.25v

Tags: go, ethereum, channel

```
func (m *FairMix) runSource(closed chan struct{}, s *mixSource) {
    defer m.wg.Done()
    defer close(s.next)
    for s.it.Next() {
        n := s.it.Node()

        fmt.Println("discmix Addsource : ", n.ID())
        select {
        case s.next <- n:
            fmt.Println("s.next <- n :", n.ID())
        case m.fromAny <- n:
            fmt.Println("m.fromAny <- n :", n.ID())
        case <-closed:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Ethereum geth 1.9.25v code.

In the `select` operation, these two `s.next` & `m.fromAny` variables both are waiting for `n`.

But when I run the program, `case s.next <- n` is being picked more frequently in comparison to case `m.fromAny <- n`.

Can I know which case would be selected first? Is there some algorithm of picking the cases if multiple cases are ready?

Comment: Ok channels only send their value one time so when you do this s.Next and s.fromAny are both in waiting state and it cannot be determined who will receive the value. https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you the Go Tour. In Go Tour, they have easy to understand hands-on playground where they covered the behavior of `select` as well.

Link to [Go Tour on **select**](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5)

So, a `select` blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case. It chooses one at random if multiple are ready.

And, it's not just about `n` but also about `s.next` and `m.fromAny`.

So, let's consider these two cases:

```
// For this case to be selected s.next should be ready
case s.next <- n


// For this case to be selected m.fromAny should be ready
case m.fromAny <- n
```

So, suppose `s.next` and `m.fromAny` both are ready at the same time, any case could be selected at random (described in the definition as well).

`n` is available, so it depends on the receiver channels: `s.next` and `m.fromAny`.

Hence, we can't decide for sure which case would be selected if multiple are ready.